# key value pair mapping in ansible to pass run the role with the appropriate value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am new to ansible. I have a small scenario.
So I pass the name of the branch using ansible when I run it.
In my play book I have:

```
# Deploy docker container
- include_role:
    name: devops/deployment.docker
  vars:
    docker_name: "docker name is based on the branch id develop dev if UAT test if master then it should be prod"
  when: build_type in "develop master UAT"
```

and in devops/deployment.docker I have a role which deploy a docker image.

```
- name: push docker container
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ docker.registery }}/docker_name"
    source: build
    build: 
      nocache: true
      path: "{{ travis.base_build_path }}"
    tag: "{{ ucd.component_version }}"
    push: yes
```

So I send build_type as develop,UAT or master when I run the ansible this role will be called. Now there is an issue:

I need to build my image based on the branch so the code needs to be intelligent and when I send develop it should go search for the key assigned to develop and get the related docker name and build it. something similar to this:

```
{
 develop: {
  dockerName:dev
 },
 master: {
  dockerName: prod
  },
 UAT: {
   dockerName: test
 }
}
```

If anyone help me how to do it in ansible I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR;

```
- name: push docker container
  vars:
    docker_name: "{{ vars[build_type].dockerName }}"
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ docker.registery }}/{{ docker_name }}"
    source: build
    build: 
      nocache: true
      path: "{{ travis.base_build_path }}"
    tag: "{{ ucd.component_version }}"
    push: yes
```

## Vars notation

Ansible has 2 notations to access dict items:

- The dot notation: `{{ my_var.my_key.my_subkey }}`
- The bracket notation: `{{ my_var['my_key']['my_subkey'] }}`

You can mix those two notations as you wish

- `{{ my_var.my_key['my_subkey'] }}`
- `{{ my_var['my_key'].my_subkey }}`

Note that lists can be accessed the same way using their index:

- `{{ my_list.0 }}`
- `{{ my_list[0] }}`

## Vars "access point"

Each of your environment definition is a first level var. You can normally call those vars in a template expression directly, e.g. `{{ master.dockerName }}`. But those vars are also available through the first level `vars` dict so the following is exactly equivalent `{{ vars.master.dockerName }}`.

## Finally...

Knowing the above and that you are sending the name of the relevant key in the `build_type` variable, you can get the expected value with: `{{ vars[build_type].dockerName }}`

---

## Unrelated to your current question

Concerning your `include_role` condition:

```
when: build_type in "develop master UAT"
```

Note that this will work for the value `"develop"` as you expect, but will also match for `"AT"`, `"mast"`, `"devel"` or even `"op mas"`. That might break the rest of your operations in case of a typo.

To make sure you match the exact word, put your matches in a list and the comparison will move from `"is it a substring of"` to `"is it an element of"`

```
when: build_type in ["develop", "master", "UAT"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this work with any version of ansible?

Comment: I am going to try it but first I wanted to double check with you. I will let you know how it gores :)

Comment: You're on SO my friend. People here expect you to try first then ask a question if your are having a problem ;)

Comment: Another question: how do you define nested variable as my example in ansible my_var you defined?

Comment: Is this example good to follow? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html

Comment: Here is my list: {
 develop: {
  dockerName:dev
 },
 master: {
  dockerName: prod
  },
 UAT: {
   dockerName: test
 }
}

Comment: This is not a list. It is a dictionary, the same that you already posted in your question. And I took for granted it was declared as top level vars. If this is not the case, please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question with the relevant details. Regarding creating nested var, you can have a look at [learn yml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

Comment: Actually worked like a charm and I should say you are the best and awesome :D
Your answer was one of the most clear and easy to understand one based on my experience in stackoverflow

Comment: Also I have another question if you can kindly  take a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794199/import-an-inventory-fole-to-another-in-ansible

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works, but there are several ways this could be achieved.

Assuming you are passing variables from the command line while running `ansible-playbook`.

This would be your command, which you might be knowing already.

`ansible-playbook mydocker-playbook.yml --extra-vars "build_type=develop"`

Following is an example how you could achieve this.

`mydocker-playbook.yaml`

```
---
- name: Docker deployment
  hosts: devops
  become: yes
  roles:
    - devops-role
```

And your task could be something like this

```
- name: push docker container
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ docker.registery }}/{{item.name}}"
    source: build
    build: 
      nocache: true
      path: "{{ travis.base_build_path }}"
    tag: "{{ ucd.component_version }}"
    push: yes
  when: build_type == item.type
  with_items:
    - { name: "dev", type: "develop" }
    - { name: "master", type: "prod" }
    - { name: "UAT", type: "test" }
```

The task iterates over the given list. But executes only when the build_type is one of the values of `type`. And assigns your docker name with `{{item.name}}` i.e. either `dev`, or `master`, or `UAT`.

Again, there are several ways we can do this, this is just one of them.

Hope this is helpful.