# import an variable file to another in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am new to ansible.
I have 2 variable files one is global and another is environment specific.
Here is the global one in global/group_var/all.yaml folder:

```
  rel:
    deployment:
      webui:
        dockerName: "rel"
        dockerTag: "Dev_{{ travis.build_number }}"
```

And the specific one is in develop/group_var/all.yaml folder

```
docker:
  registery: "xxxx"
```

is there any way I can import global/group_var/all.yaml to develop/group_var/all.yaml

```
import global/group_var/all.yaml
docker:
  registery: "xxxx"
```

so develop/group_var/all.yaml becomes:

```
rel:
  deployment:
    webui:
      dockerName: "rel"
docker:
  registery: "xxxx"
dockerTag: "Dev_1111"
```

Thanks

Comment: Those aren't inventory files. Those are variable files.

Comment: @larsks Thanks I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to read the global variables into a dictionary. For example

```
$ cat develop/group_var/all.yaml
global: "{{ lookup('file', 'global/group_var/all.yaml')|from_yaml }}"
docker:
  registery: "xxxx"
```

the playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: develop/group_var/all.yaml
    - debug:
        var: global
    - debug:
        var: docker
```

gives

```
    "global": {
        "rel": {
            "deployment": {
                "webui": {
                    "dockerName": "rel"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    "docker": {
        "registery": "xxxx"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works for static variables but for dockerTag: "Dev_{{ travis.build_number }}" does not replace the template? is it not possible for that case?